# Where to save application data in windows?

Tags: windows, pyqt, software-design, application-data

I am trying to make a windows application. In this application, some files get modified as a user add or delete an entry. I saved these files on the application folder itself.
But After making binary file I installed it, As I try to add a entry it get crashed.

So, I figured out the issue. The windows doesn't allow to modified files inside C:\Program Files.
So, I installed it in other drive and it works. It solved my issue temporarily but I want to know how other application works in windows.

Where do those applications save their data?
I am not talking about some data which get saved in "Documents" but something which is essential need to modified every time user makes change like theme, formates.

Answer (score 1):

No user access is allowed to the "program folder", and that's for good: it is a *system* folder, and it should only be accessed for *system* related operations (like installing or uninstalling a program).

There are many places where "program data" can be stored depending on the situation, and [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) provides access to their paths, according to the category location. What you might be interested in are:

- `ConfigLocation`: Returns a directory location where user-specific configuration files should be written. This may be either a generic value or application-specific, and the returned path is never empty.
- `AppDataLocation`: Returns a directory location where persistent application data can be stored. This is an application-specific directory.
- `AppLocalDataLocation`: As the previous one, but Windows specific.
- `AppConfigLocation`: Returns a directory location where user-specific configuration files should be written. This is an application-specific directory, and the returned path is never empty.

Those paths (along with the others listed in the documentation) can be accessed using the following static methods:

- [`standardLocations(locationType)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#standardLocations): returns a *list* of paths for the requested location type, in order of priority (the first is usually the preferred one);
- [`writableLocation(locationType)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation): returns the preferred path for which write access is allowed (usually the first of the `standardLocations()`);

If you need to store the user configuration, you can use `QStandardPaths.writableLocation(AppConfigLocation)`, while if you have some user-specific internal data that is used by the application (email database, document templates, etc) `QStandardPaths.writableLocation(AppLocalDataLocation)` should be a good choice.

In both cases, those paths may not exist, so you need to ensure that and eventually create them, possibly by using `QDir(path)`:

```
    dataPath = QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation(AppLocalDataLocation)
    dataPathDir = QtCore.QDir(dataPath)
    if not dataPathDir.exists():
        # create the directory (including parent directories if they don't exist);
        # that the argument of mkpath is relative to the QDir's object path, so
        # using '.' means that it will create the actual dataPath
        dataPathDir.mkpath('.')
```

Note that for all of the above (especially the last 3) it's required that you correctly set both the [organizationName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#organizationName-prop) *and* the [applicationName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop).